# How to create a numeric index from a string variable?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, panel-data

I'm working with panel data and I am stuck in this situation:

[image]

What I want is to create a numeric ID (NumID) using Country as a reference, like this:
[image]
Can someone help me? Many thanks!

Comment: Some many different ways.. `pd.factorize`, scikit `LabelEncoder`, etc

Comment: *Please* don't post data / code as images. You should paste it directly into your question then use code formatting (the `{}` button).
Also, you haven't included what you've already tried, and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

A few options:

#### groupby & ngroup

```py
df['NumID_1'] = df.groupby('Country').ngroup() + 1
```

#### factorize

```py
df['NumID_2'] = df['Country'].factorize()[0] + 1
```

#### Categorical

Depending on your needs, you may also look into using pandas' [`Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html) datatype:

```py
df['NumID_3'] = df['Country'].astype('category')
```

```py
  Country  Year Var1 Var2 Var3  NumID  NumID_1  NumID_2 NumID_3
0  Brazil  2000    A    B    C      1        1        1  Brazil
1  Brazil  2001    X    Y    Z      1        1        1  Brazil
2  Brazil  2002    F    F    H      1        1        1  Brazil
3  Brazil  2003    P    3    K      1        1        1  Brazil
4   Chile  2000    A    B    C      2        2        2   Chile
5   Chile  2001    X    Y    Z      2        2        2   Chile
6   Chile  2002    F    F    H      2        2        2   Chile
7   Chile  2003    P    3    K      2        2        2   Chile
```

Comment: Perfect! I used the factorize! Works fine! Many thanks!

Comment: @RicardodosSantos Glad it worked for you. Please consider accepting / upvoting if this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try this to make num id from country :

import pandas as pd
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype

labels, uniques = pd.factorize(["Brazil","Brazil","Brazil","Brazil","Chile","Chile","Chile","Chile"])

print("Numeric Representation : \n", labels) 
print("Unique Values : \n", uniques) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/he7UJ.png)